# Reductive amination in case of secondary amines

Tags: reaction-mechanism, amines

When an aldehyde or a ketone undergoes reductive amination when a primary amine is acting,the mechanism follows a pathway through hemiaminal and imine,what happens when a secondary amine is acting on the given carbonyl ? There will be no hydrogen on the amine nitrogen in this case to facilitate loss of water with the hydroxyl group of the hemiaminal.How does the reaction proceed then?

Comment: Secondary amines undergo reductive amination perfectly well via the iminium ion. This explains it clearly https://www.chemistryscore.com/reactions/reductive-amination/

Comment: Did you read @Waylander's link? The mechanism is there.

Comment: Yes I did , actually I was not able to follow the answer there , what I was able to gather from there was that the reducing agent , LiAlH4 in my case , will substitute the OH and nitrogen will grab a hydrogen from water

Comment: Sodiumtriacetoxyborohydride in DCM is my reagent of choice for reductive aminations. LiAlH4 will just reduce your ketone before it reacts with the amine

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In modern organic synthesis, reductive amination of aldehydes and ketones is considered one of the important and principal ways to make secondary and tertiary amines. It is a powerful and reliable strategy for the formation of $\ce{C–N}$ bonds. One of the advantages of the reductive amination is it can avoid the problem of over-alkylation that is always the problem with direct alkylation of amines with alkyl halides.

Reductive amination can be achieved following either a one-step or a two-step procedure. In both procedures, an amine and a carbonyl compound condense to form an imine (with primary amine) or iminium ion (with secondary amine). This imine or iminium ion is then reduced *in situ* (one-step reaction) or separated and subsequently reduced (two-step reaction) to form an amine product. Following is the suggested mechanism for reductive amination:

[image: Reductive Amination]

Most common condition is sodium triacetoxyborohydride ($\ce{NaB(OAc)3H}$) in THF or dichloroethane (DCE) under slighly acidic conditions (common acid used is acetic acid)(Ref.1).

**Reference:**

1. Ahmed F. Abdel-Magid, Kenneth G. Carson, Bruce D. Harris, Cynthia A. Maryanoff, Rekha D. Shah, “Reductive Amination of Aldehydes and Ketones with Sodium Triacetoxyborohydride. Studies on Direct and Indirect Reductive Amination Procedures,” *J. Org. Chem.* **1996**, *61(11)*, 3849-3862 (https://doi.org/10.1021/jo960057x).

Comment: A good answer. A useful additive for reductive aminations that proceed in poor yield (or not at all) is Titanium (IV) alkoxide - Ti(OEt)4 or Ti(iOPr)4.